# Unable to get property 'propertyName' of undefined or null reference in angular 6

Tags: json, angular

I am getting the following issue

Unable to get property 'senderDetails' of undefined or null reference

I am using the following code in angular 6

```
<tr *ngIf="itemList.senderDetails?.length !=null">
<th scope="row">Sender Owner</th>
<td><strong>ID</strong>{{itemList.senderId}} |<strong>Name</strong>{{itemList.sender}}</td>
</tr>
```

the above code runs fine in chrom but it throws error of undefined or null reference in IE edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this

```
<tr *ngIf="itemList?.senderDetails?.length">
<th scope="row">Sender Owner</th>
<td><strong>ID</strong>{{itemList.senderId}} |<strong>Name</strong>{{itemList.sender}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your itemList is undefined at start. You can

1. Initialize your itemList

   itemList = {};

   or if you are using a class to store itemList data

   itemList : ItemList = new ItemList();
2. Add a second *ngIf to an outer element so inside code will not be executed while itemList is undefined *ngIf="itemList != undefined"

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

That is because at the time of rendering the page(view), itemList object is null or undefined. If you are getting data for itemList from an async call(api's), these kind of problems will arise. So we should always check the object whether it is null or undefined then if it is not, we can access its properties. In your condition you can use below code for 'if stattement'.

```
<tr *ngIf="itemList && (itemList.senderDetails?.length !=null")>
```